# mysql transaction with multiple queries not working Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using a package to simplify my RDS queries [Link Here](https://github.com/jeremydaly/data-api-client) , If i use on nested query that works but get an error when  using multiple queries here's my code

```
insert = await rds_client.transaction()
        .query(`insert into RFP (AccountID, OtherServicesOffered, AssignedTo, Note, CreatedBy,RFPType,RenewalID) values (:AccountID, :OtherServicesOffered, :AssignedTo, :Note, :CreatedBy,:RFPType,:RenewalID)`,
        {
            AccountID:data.AccountID,
            OtherServicesOffered:data.OtherServicesOffered,
            AssignedTo:data.AssignedTo,
            Note:data.Note,
            CreatedBy:data.CreatedBy,
            RenewalID:(data.RenewalID) ? data.RenewalID : null,
            RFPType:(data.RFPType) ? data.RFPType : 0,
        }
    )
     .query((r) => [codestringCurrentlyOffered, {RFPID: r.insertId}] )
     .query((r) => [codestringToBeQuoted, {RFPID: r.insertId}] )
     .commit();
    }
```

if i comment out the `.query((r) => [codestringToBeQuoted, {RFPID: r.insertId}] )`
everything seems to work normally, this is the error when i try to run both together

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vytaldb`.`RFPToBeQuoted2Product`, CONSTRAINT `RFPToBeQuoted2Product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
```

there is a foreign key contrainst on both tables, if i remove that it starts working with both queries,Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Barmar Post Updated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `r` is only the result of the first `INSERT` query in the second `query()` call. In the third call, `r` contains the result of `codestringCurrentlyOffered`, not the query that inserted into `RFP`, so `r.insertid` is not the ID of the new `RFP` row.

So you need to perform both queries in the scope of the same `r` variable.

```
insert = await rds_client.transaction()
        .query(`insert into RFP (AccountID, OtherServicesOffered, AssignedTo, Note, CreatedBy,RFPType,RenewalID) values (:AccountID, :OtherServicesOffered, :AssignedTo, :Note, :CreatedBy,:RFPType,:RenewalID)`,
        {
            AccountID:data.AccountID,
            OtherServicesOffered:data.OtherServicesOffered,
            AssignedTo:data.AssignedTo,
            Note:data.Note,
            CreatedBy:data.CreatedBy,
            RenewalID:(data.RenewalID) ? data.RenewalID : null,
            RFPType:(data.RFPType) ? data.RFPType : 0,
        }
    );
await insert.query(r => [codestringCurrentlyOffered, {RFPID: r.insertId}] );
await insert.query(r = [codestringToBeQuoted, {RFPID: r.insertId}]);
await insert.commit();
```

Comment: That does seem like the possible solution , but unfortunately getting the same error! ,  so  in the above solution r issue is still there i think